# How to allow users to see a document's metadata but not its contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to create a permission level that allows users to see the metadata of documents in a document library but disallows them to open and read the document. I naively thought this would be accomplished by enabling the "View Items" permission and disabling the "Open Items" permission. But obviously the meaning of these permissions is different from what I assumed. The "View Items" permission by itself seems to enable users not only to see the document metadata but also to open and read the document.

Is there any way to achieve the desired permission level?

Comment: I also need this for document sets. Certain users should be allowed to see the document set's metadata, but should not be allowed to open the document set.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this by accident.

We have a document library with PDFs and metadata. If you allocate the permission 'view only' the users can see the list with metadata, but when they open the pdf they get access denied.

We have office web application but for this particular site they are turned off. However I believe that a word, excel or pp document it would be opened in read only. Pdfs behaves differently.